# Proving with divisibility

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

I have never written any proofs (except high school geometry) in my life, so I'm not sure what exactly the proper formatting should be.

Involving divisibility,
the proposition states:

**Let $a, b,$ and $c$ be integers. If $a|b$ and $a|c$ then $a|(b+c)$**

This is what I wrote, but I'm really not sure if I'm going the right direction with this.

Let **$m$** and **$n$** be integers

Let **$b = am$** and **$c = an$**

**$b + c = am + an = a (m + n)$**

Let integer **$k = m + n$**

**$b + c = a (k)$**

Then, **$a | (b + c)$**

I'm starting a proving class this semester without any background or experience in proving. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let **m** and **n** be integers
>   Let **b = am** and **c = an**

Here I can see you're using the definition of divisibility, but I'd write it differently: "Suppose $a,b,c$ are integers such that $a | b$ and $a | c$. Then $b=am$ and $c=an$ for some integers $m,n$."

The important difference is that the hypothesis of the problem tells you to  start with $a,b$ and $c$, and then  the conditions on $a,b,c$ determine $m$ and $n$, not the other way around.

> **b + c = am + an = a (m + n)**

This line looks good, and it's the key step on the proof.

> Let integer **k = m + n**
>   **b + c = a (k)**

This is right, but I don't think it's necessary; you can actually end at your previous line because since $m$ and $n$ are integers, you know that $m+n$ is an integer too, so you have written $b+c$ as $a$ times an integer already, which means, as you conclude, that $a$ divides $b+c$.

Comment: I can definitely see the differences. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)